# N long tuple as optional argument

Tags: julia

I would like to have an `N` long tuple as an optional argument of a function but I do not know how to provide a `N` long default value:

```
function create_grid(d::Int64, n::Tuple{Vararg{Int64, N}}; xmin::Tuple{Vararg{Float64, N}}) where N
```

I understand `xmin` should be declared with a default value such as `xmin::Tuple{Vararg{Float64, N}}::0.`, but this is evidently wrong as it is defaulting to a `Float` instead of `Tuple`. How can I state I want a `N` long tuple as optional argument defaulting to (eg.) `0.` for all the elements if the argument is not provided explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is - you just provide the default as a one element tuple:

```
function somefun(d::Int64, n::Tuple{Vararg{Int64, N}}; xmin::Tuple{Vararg{Float64, N}}=(0.0,)) where N
    println("d=$d n=$n xmin=$xmin")
end
```

To understand how it works just note that:

```
Tuple{Vararg{Int, 2}} == typeof((2,2)) 
#and
Tuple{Vararg{Int, 1}} == typeof((2,))
```

so you needed 1-element tuple as a default.

Let's test it:

```
julia> somefun(4,(4,))
d=4 n=(4,) xmin=(0.0,)
```

This works as expected.

Finally, note that providing a 2-element tuple as the second argument without the third one will throw an error because the sizes do not match:

```
julia> somefun(4,(4,5))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching #somefun#1(::Tuple{Float64}, ::typeof(somefun), ::Int64, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64})
```

If you want to workaround this you need another constructor:

```
function somefun(d::Int64, n::Tuple{Vararg{Int64, N}}; xmin::Tuple{Vararg{Float64, N}}= tuple(zeros(length(n))...)) where N
    println("d=$d n=$n xmin=$xmin")
end
```

Testing:

```
julia> somefun(4,(4,5))
d=4 n=(4, 5) xmin=(0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: The issue is that I want to be able to call `somefun(4,(4,5))`, without `xmin` and then `xmin` should be `(0.,0.)` in the function by default. That is what I explain in my question.